# Sending firebase cloud function errors in asynchronous functions to the user

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use firebase cloud functions for the backend of a webapp. I have tried to create a function that creates a user as follows:

```js
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    //validate email
    if (!verifyEmail(data.email))
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", `The email ${data.email} is not formatted correctly`)

    if (data.password !== data.confirmPassword)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", `Passwords do not match`)

    if (!data.username)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", `Username cannot be empty`)

    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password
    }).then(user => {
        admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
            username: data.username
        }).catch(error => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", `An internal error occured creating the user`, error)
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", `An internal error occured creating the user`, error)
    })
})
```

When an incorrectly formatted email is passed in, the error is passed onto the user, however, when a failure occurs on the creation of a user the error is printed out on the backend logs, and not sent to the user. Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `async`/`await` with `.then()` which is not something that is generally recommended as it leads to this kind of confusion. Try something like this:

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    //validate email
    if (!verifyEmail(data.email))
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", `The email ${data.email} is not formatted correctly`)

    if (data.password !== data.confirmPassword)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", `Passwords do not match`)

    if (!data.username)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", `Username cannot be empty`)

    try {
      const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password
      });
      await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        username: data.username
      });
    } catch (err) {
      functions.logger.error("Unexpected error creating user", err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", `An internal error occured creating the user`);
    }
})
```